# Can't inject dependency in service

Tags: c#, servicestack

I have a service that looks like this:

```
public class StuffService : ServiceStack.Service
{
    private IStuffHandler _handler;

    public StuffService(IStuffHandler handler)
    {
        _handler = handler;
    }

    public void Post(RequestMessage message)
    {
        _handler.HandleIt();
    }
}
```

In the StuffService, _handler should be instantiated as the following class:

```
public class StuffHandler : IStuffHandler
{
    public void HandleIt()
    {
        //do stuff
    }
}
```

And in a seperate file:

```
  public class ServiceAppHost : AppHostHttpListenerBase
    {
        public ServiceAppHost() :
        base("CoolConnectionString", typeof(ServiceAppHost).Assembly)
        {
        }

        public override void Configure(Container container)
        {
            this.Plugins.Add(new SwaggerFeature());
            container.RegisterAs<IStuffHandler, StuffHandler>();
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ServiceAppHost appHost = new ServiceAppHost();
        appHost.Init();
        appHost.Start("http://localhost:7894/");
        Console.Read();
    }
```

Now, I can't figure out how to set IStuffHandler to an instance of StuffHandler. I have followed [this page](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/The-IoC-container) on the official ServiceStack documentation pages. I have tried several different methods on that linked page, but I can't get ServiceStack to instantiate _handler as a StuffHandler instance. What do I need to do?

Comment: Wouldn't you just change the declaration to private StuffHandler _handler, since it's already implicitly an IStuffHandler?

Comment: If _handler becomes a StuffHandler it can't be mocked in unit tests anymore. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the order of your dependency registration wrong, it should instead be:

```
container.RegisterAs<StuffHandler, IStuffHandler>();
```

An alternative registration is to register an instance of the type like this, using container.Register:

```
container.Register<IStuffHandler>(c => new StuffHandler());
```

In your Services dependencies are injected by **public properties**:

```
public class StuffService : ServiceStack.Service
{
    public IStuffHandler Handler { get; set; }

    public void Post(RequestMessage message)
    {
        Handler.HandleIt();
    }
}
```

or via the **constructor**:

```
public class StuffService : ServiceStack.Service
{
    private IStuffHandler _handler;

    public StuffService(IStuffHandler handler)
    {
        _handler = handler;
    }

    public void Post(RequestMessage message)
    {
        _handler.HandleIt();
    }
}
```

Either of these examples will inject your dependency into your service.

Comment: Thanks for the great example. There was a small error in the second line of code that I edited for you, as the second one should use Register, not RegisterAs.

Answer (score 4):

DependencyInjection needs somewhere it can inject the dependencies - in your case there is no way, the private field is to be set.
You either need an constructor, which accepts an `IStuffHandler` or some other public method/field/property supported by your DI-container.

In your startmethod you will then have to call something like `container.resolve<MyService>()` to get an instance from the container.

Comment: No problem, I can add a constructor that accepts an IStuffHandler instance. Post edited! Can you explain the simplest way to achieve my goal?

Comment: Well after your constructor is there, the DI-container should do the trick.